# Passing the drawing in panel to picture box of another form possible?

Tags: c#, image, winforms

So i have form that i use to draw signatures and it draws on a panel, when i click save in saves in a specific folder location. What i want to know is it is possible that after i click save the picture that i draw will automatically go to the picture box of my main form. Please enlighten me with this one.

Here is a screenshot of my software *all information in the database are for testing only.

[image]

Comment: If you have a reference to the pbox or the form you can do it of course. you may want to pass that reference to the 2nd form in its constructor.

Comment: Do you want to show the drawing painted on the dialog or the Bitmap in the file (the results) saved on disc? These two *could* be different. Even a lot different, depending on the Bitmap format used when saving the Image. As for the method, TaW already mentioned it: you could *inject* the drawing dialog constructor with the current instance of the MainForm. The MainForm, IMO, should provide a Public Method/Property that lets you specify a Bitmap object or a File Name.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: oooohh.. BSU. HAHHA. Malvar campus?

Comment: If you saved the image in a directory, you can just get that directory and display the image on the next form on_load method. @DietherNoche

Comment: @TerribleDog Balayan sir Hahaha thank you !

Comment: But i cant seem to put it into a text box in the old form because i am not loading the form passing text seems not the right thing to do ?